# Can we read the quanternion in terms of eigenvalues of equivalent 3D rotation matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, lie-groups, rotations, quaternions

What is the relationship between a quanternion and the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of equivalent 3D rotation matrix?

A relation in terms of $\lambda_r, \mathbf{v}_{\lambda_r}, \mathbf{v}_{\lambda_1}$ in the following: (Correct me about the details if I am wrong)

If I understand correctly, a 3D rotation matrix has an eigenvalue $\lambda_1=1$ and two conjugate eigenvalues $\lambda_r, \overline{\lambda_r}$.

- The axis of 3D rotation will be $\mathbf{v}_{\lambda_1}$ (The eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda_1=1$).
- The angle of 3D rotation will be $\operatorname{arctan2}\left(\operatorname{Im}(\lambda_r), \operatorname{Re}(\lambda_r)\right)$, where $\operatorname{arctan2}$ is the [two-argument arctangent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2).

Can we write the quaternion's four coordinates for such 3D rotation in terms of $\lambda_r, \mathbf{v}_{\lambda_r}, \mathbf{v}_{\lambda_1}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. First of all, any correspondence of quaternions with rotations depends on an arbitrary choice of three orthogonal spatial directions to correspond to the there kinds of imaginary units in the quaternions, so at the very least one would need to use that correspondence (rather than a nice formula) to go from spatial data like the axis to quaternions.

Second, even fixing the correspondence, there are two (opposite) unit quaternions for every rotation; no formula can uniformly make a choice between those two possibilities in a continuous way.

Third, given an axis and a characteristic polynomial of a rotation (so with one root $1$ and two other complex conjugate roots of absolute value $1$), there are two rotations with that axis and that characteristic polynomial (they turn in opposite directions). So one cannot even determine the rotation uniquely from the data you provide; this gives another problem similar to the second point.

Comment: Thank you, this revealed the bug in my thinking, which let me to the confusion. However, I need to refresh my mind on Quaternions and re-read the answer carefully to understand it fully.

Comment: One bug in my thinking was that the eigenvalues-eigenvectors decomposition of a matrix (characteristic polynomial) does not determine the matrix fully (the original  matrix cannot be always reconstructed from the set of $(\lambda, \mathbf{v}_{\lambda})$ pairs). Am I correct?

Comment: @SohailSi The problem with eigenvectors here is that they only really exist for the real eigenvalue $\lambda=1$. For the other eigenvalues, eigenvectors only exist in the formal complexification of the vector space (a _complex_ three dimensional space) and they cannot in any sensible way be made to correspond to quaternions. So though one can in principle recover a matrix from a basis of complex eigenvectors with their (complex) eigenvalues, that cannot be used in any way in the correspondence with the quaternions.

Comment: Many thanks for taking time to share the insight.